# FreeBSD's __isthreaded equivalent in Linux

Tags: linux, porting

FreeBSD's stdio.h has an extern declaration of variable '__isthreaded'.
This variable is zero until a process has created a thread. It is used to avoid calling locking functions in libc when they are not required.

But this is not a portable way of checking presence of thread. Linux does not support this.
Do we have any equivalent Variable or API in Linux?
I am trying to port some code from FreeBSD to Linux.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps it does not exist and you could `#define __isthreaded 1`

Comment: But it does not help to have the same behaviour.. As an example, if I call pthread_mutex_lock() only if __isthreaded is not zero. With the above #define, lock will be invoked always..

Comment: Yes, you would always call the synchronization primitives. Not a big deal these days. If you really wanted to, you could count the number of threads by using `/proc/self/task/` and counting the number of directories inside, but that is much slower.

Comment: Thanks Basile. In case of lock/unlock, __isthreaded could be an optimisation and I hope there is no harm avoiding the check for __isthreaded in Linux.

Comment: Yes, my point is that such a feature does not exist in Linux (AFAIK) and you should bypass it by always running synchronization primitives (which in the single-threaded case are *fast*). BTW, Linux does not have only one libc (usually [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) but you could use [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/) etc...) and your question is libc specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What glibc does to provide almost the same feature is to define stub functions for most of the pthread library in glibc. These calls do nothing and are very fast.

Once libpthread.so is linked in, its symbols override the weak glibc symbols and then the real functions are called.

So include pthread and call the locking functions, but don't link with it.

Comment: I guess that is the reason pthread_mutex_lock() is a noop on Linux if not linked to lpthread.